# defining integral using trapezoidal rule(beginner)

Tags: python

My programm aims in defining the integral of a given function between two numbers (x1,x2),using n trapezoids.As it seems,my department's auto evaluating programm gives different answers than the ones of mine.Problem is that i cant find anything wrong in my code...

```
def funct(x):
    val= -(1./6)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)
    return val


x1,x2,n=input()
Dx=float(x2-x1)/n
Sum=0
i=x1+Dx
while i<x2:
    val=funct(i)
    Sum+=val
    i+=Dx
Sum=2*Sum
val1=funct(x1)
val2=funct(x2)
S=(Dx/2)*(val1+val2+Sum)
print "%.3f" %S
```

Comment: What values of x1 and x2 are you using, and what should the answer be?

Comment: x1 and x2 can be any real number as long as x1<x2 and n is always a positive integer.As for the answers,input:-88.787529, 83.494648, 1942.What my programm prints:-322680995.303.What auto correction prints:-322005423.436

Comment: May I say that your style is rather baroque? in particular the  statement `Sum=Sum*2`...  Another remark: due to a very established habit in mathematics first and programming later, one letter variables `i, j, k, m, n` and, to a much lesser degree, `l` are used to denote integers used as indices or counts. E.g., a much more idiomatic usage would have been `x_i = x1+Dx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to rounding issues, your `while` cycle always includes last value of `x`, try using exact integer arithmetic

```
x0, x1 = -88.787529, 83.494648
n = 1942

dx = (x1-x0)/n
s = 0
i = 1
while i < n:

   # if we allow i == n, in the following row we'll have
   #   x0 + n*dx = x0 + n * (x1-x0) / n = x0 + x1 - x0 = x1
   # but we want to exclude the last term

   s = s + funct(x0+i*dx)
   i = i + 1
result = (s + funct(x0)/2.0 + funct(x1)/2.0)*dx
```

Comment: Don't loop over a real variable like that, either use integers or use a tolerance (e.g., `while x_i < (x1-0.1*dx)`), because you can't take for granted that rounding will not be an issue.

Comment: oh i see,i was worried about that thing but wasnt sure it could actually be the problem.the programm runs great now

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably some sort of homework question, but in general, don't reinvent the wheel:

```
import numpy

def funct(x):
    return -(1./6)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x+2)*(x-4)

x1, x2 = -88.787529, 83.494648
n = 1942
# n "panels", n+1 points
x = numpy.linspace(x1, x2, n+1)
y = funct(x)

result = numpy.trapz(y, x)
```

Comment: as a matter of fact,i am aware of the numpy function.its just that i couldnt skip the whole thinking procedure.you know..for the sake of programming.thanks though